# Python Google OAuth2 gives "TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'"

Tags: python, flask, gmail

The code [Google provides](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending) to send email using OAuth2 is in Python 2, and I am trying to send email using Python 3. The message body is causing an error.

The basic process to send an email is:
Create an f string for the message body.
Call `create message` which executes `message = MIMEText(message_text)`
This function then calls `return {'raw': base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_string())}`

... which generates the message 
`TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`

Why? How do I get this to not throw this error?
.

Here's the code (mostly taken from the Google Gmail example linked above):

```
def create_message(sender, to, subject, message_text):
    message = MIMEText(message_text)
    message['to'] = to
    message['from'] = sender
    message['subject'] = subject
    return {'raw': base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_string())}

def send_reset_email(user):
    token = user.get_reset_token()
    msg = create_message(sender='me@gmail.com', to=user.email,
             subject = 'Password Reset Request',
    message_text = f'''To reset your password visit the following link:
    {url_for('reset_token', token=token, _external=True)}
    ''')
    credentials = get_credentials()
    http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
    service = discovery.build('gmail', 'v1', http=http)
    send_message()
```

And here's the trace:

```
  File "C:\home\app\routes.py", line 187, in send_reset_email)
  File "C:\home\app\routes.py", line 169, in create_message
     return {'raw': base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_string())}
  File "C:\home\b\base64.py", line 118, in urlsafe_b64encode
     return b64encode(s).translate(_urlsafe_encode_translation)
  File "C:\home\b\base64.py", line 58, in b64encode
    hencoded = binascii.b2a_base64(s, newline=False)
```

Comment: Does this still fail if you change `message.as_string() => message`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code whats i can see is

```
return {'raw': base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_string())}
```

which should be changed to

```
return {'raw': base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_bytes())}
```

Its good to use google code but sometimes it doesn't work as intended.

While if you are sending email with attachment you need to change the last line to just an extra information that may help you.

```
return {'raw': base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_bytes()).decode()}
```

Comment: That seemed to work, because now it's failing on this line: ```store = oauth2client.file.Storage(credential_path)``` with ```AttributeError: module 'oauth2client' has no attribute 'file'```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this, I think strings are handled differently.
This has some information about potential string issues from Py2 to Py3, similarities might help you resolve some issues: http://python3porting.com/problems.html

```
message_body = "some message"
# now message_text needs this encoded string
message_text = message_body.encode('utf-8')
```